# How can I write a GEOTIFF in Java?

Tags: java, gis, geospatial, tiff, geotiff

I want to write a GEOTIFF, with all the geographic metadata in Java. Which library etc. works best for this purpose?

Comment: Although I've provided my own scraping-the-bottom-of-the-barrel solution, there must be a better way that is pure Java? As well as being complicated and potentially difficult to maintain, my solution would require a recompile for each platform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GeoTIFF-JAI should be able to do this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/geotiff-jai/

GeoTIFF-AI incorporates Extensible-TIFF-JAI, which is an extensible codec allowing tiled images, etc.

There's also a GeoTIFF metadata adapter for Java ImageIO at:

www.gelbin.org/code/

and the NetCDF library also includes a GeoTIFF writer, documented at:

www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/v4.0/javadocAll/ucar/nc2/geotiff/GeotiffWriter.html

Comment: It looks like GeoTIFF-JAI hasn't been updated in well over a year, but the others look like they will be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal solution but as no one else has replied in two months...

libgeotiff is a pretty good open source C++ library that I have successfully used in production code to read geotiff meta data. This could be used in Java with a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

check out geotools geotiffwriter: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) offers a pure Java-based TiFF image manipulation. I came across by following this question in [GIS-Stack-Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119134/looking-for-an-open-source-java-based-geotiff-library). It offers a range of functionalities to manipulate GeoTiFF.